# сетевое администрирование. коллоквиум

Tags: сеть, администрирование, маршрутизация

1. Многие сетевые проблемы бывают связаны с кабелем. Что необходимо проверить в случае возникновения проблем?
2. Для увеличения длины сети что лучше использовать и почему? ( Мосты, репиторы, маршрутизаторы, коммутаторы, шлюзы).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 1):

1. Наличие физ. повреждений, длинну (В общем случае не более ~100м, в частном - чем меньше - тем лучше), удалённость от линий эл. передач, правильность обжатия пар (Обычно стандарты TIA/EIA-568A или TIA/EIA-568B, но вообще можно как угодно, лишь бы было зеркально)
2. Переходить на оптоволокно :)

Comment: На будущее, поощрять ответами, тех, кто не хочет учиться, здесь не принято.

Comment: Проверьте что кабель надёжно подключен к устройству. Проблемы чаще не в кабелях, а коннекторах или кабель выдёргивают по разным причинам. Для удлинения лучше использовать устройства, которые для этого и предназначены - репитеры. Потому что не надо переплачивать за функциональность, которая не нужна.